# How to properly read from a file in a certain amount of multiple characters into a char array in C?

Tags: c, string

I am pretty new to programming and I am not sure how to solve this problem. I tried doing %8s ... %52s but it does not take into account that delimiters are supposed to take up space in the substrings. So if I tried to scan in 8 spaces, a word of length 5, 1 space, and another word of length 8 it would grab the first string of letters not the spaces. This is reading from one line at a time from the file, but breaking it up into substrings, where each substring is put into a unique array.
EX:

```
        Word AnotherW
```

the first array would take in `Word`, not          (8 spaces).

```
    char firCol[8];                   //first 8 characters including delimiters
    char space[1] = {' '};            //guaranteed space
    char secCol[1] = {' '};           //space or '+'
    char thirCol[7];      //word of length 7 but if shorter includes delitimers
    char forCol[1] = {' '};           //guaranteed space
    char fifCol[10];                  //sames of 7 but length 
    char comm[52];                    // length 52 char and delimitrer

    memset(firCol, ' ', 8);
    memset(thirCol, ' ', 7);
    memset(comm, ' ', 52);

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");                                                           

    memset(info, 0, sizeof(struct Account) * TABLE_SIZE);
            //Initialize the array, set all indices equal 0 

      while(EOF != fscanf(f, "%8c %1c %1c %7c %1c %10c %52c", firCol, space, secCol, thirCol, forCol, fifCol, comm))
      {
        pass1(info, firCol, space, secCol, thirCol, forCol, fifCol, comm);
      }




/******************************/
/***MORE    INFO    ADDED******/
/******************************/


    Col 1-8    label optional
    Col 9      blank
    Col 10     + optional
    Col 11-17  mneumonic
    Col 18     blank
    Col 19     #, @, =  ... optional
    Col 20-29  (operand) label, register, ',',X optional  ...
    Col 30-31  blank
    Col 32-80  comments optional (NO PERIOD REQUIRED)


    ADDRES    START    100                               
    . tests pc forward addressing
    . tests base addressing
    . tests pc backward addressing
    NOW      +LDB     #BEGIN              load base register 
    XXX       BASE     BEGIN              tell assembler  
    YYY       LDA      BE                 A <- (m..m+2)    
    EN        RESW     4                  
    BE        WORD     2                              
    BEGIN     RESW     1
    JUNK      RESW     2200                              
    THERE     RESW     1                              
    ZZZ       LDA      JUNK                               
    MMM       STA      THERE                              
              END      NOW          


    RESULTS:

    100     ADDRES    START    100                               
    . TESTS PC FORWARD ADDRESSING
    . TESTS BASE ADDRESSING
    . TESTS PC BACKWARD ADDRESSING
    100    NOW      +LDB     #BEGIN              LOAD BASE REGISTER 
    104    XXX       BASE     BEGIN              TELL ASSEMBLER  
    104    YYY       LDA      BE                 A <- (M..M+2)    
    107    EN        RESW     4                  
    113    BE        WORD     2                              
    116    BEGIN     RESW     1
    119    JUNK      RESW     2200                              
    1ae1   THERE     RESW     1                              
    1ae4   ZZZ       LDA      JUNK                               
    1ae7   MMM       STA      THERE                              
    1aea                END      NOW                              

    Table Location      Label      Address      Use Csect
    135 0                   BE          113         main    main
    147 0                   EN          107         main    main
    231 0                   MMM        1ae7         main    main
    244 0                   NOW        100          main    main
    264 0                   XXX        104          main    main
    267 0                   YYY        104          main    main
    270 0                   ZZZ        1ae4         main    main
    312 0                   JUNK          119       main    main
    357 0                  BEGIN         116        main    main
    376 0                  THERE         1ae1       main    main
    435 0                  ADDRES       100         main    main
```

Comment: Please show the input and state what expected output.

Comment: It's hard to determine if my edit represents the intent. Please check and roll back the edit, if it doesn't.

Comment: I forgot to add in, I am trying to create a two pass assembler, the first pass  will create addresses and store the Label and its address into a hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

As `fscanf` returns the number of read items, I suppose the condition should be

```
 (7 == fscanf(f, "%7s %c %c %6s %c %9s %51s", firCol, space, secCol, thirCol, forCol, fifCol, comm))
```

Pay attention:

- to read a chacter use `%c` (without length specification)
- to read string use `%s`
- length for strings should be (ARRAY SIZE - 1)

Comment: The only thing about using %s is it looks for a string of that length but this string cannot contain ' ' (space characters) which I need to include in the char array I read in. How would I account for that? The max length of the strings for each column would be the size I made each char array but can be less. Which is when I need to account for the spaces. There will be a guarantee that the spaces will be included if the string is not the max length.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the proper way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  //TODO: Name this variables better. I cannot stress how important naming this is
  char firCol[9];        //first 8 characters including delimiters
  char plusFlag;           //space or '+'
  char thirCol[8];       //word of length 7 but if shorter includes delitimers
  char fifCol[10];       //sames of 7 but length 
  char comm[53];         // length 52 char and delimitrer

  FILE* f;  //Don't forget variables. And when asking questions with code, it's best to include everything

  //Don't worry about initializing the strings. In general, initializing variables is a good idea, but these will be clobbered.

  f = fopen("file.txt", "r");                                                    
  //Ah, dead code. It might have been something at some point. But it was killed. Now it's corpse litters the field of battle.
  //memset(info, 0, sizeof(struct Account) * TABLE_SIZE);                                  //Initialize the array, set all indices equal 0 

  //the spaces in the file are eaten by the spaces in the string literal
  //The size of the strings can vary, but the number in %8s is the maximum. It's a good safety precausion.
  // %*c eats a character and throws it away. We do this because there might be one or two whitespaces. The second of which may be important. If we put a whitespace in the string literal, it would have eaten both, throwing off the rest of the command.
  //The %c is always just one character. You don't want to read in a string for that + symbol, as it isn't terminated by a null character. %1s would work... but no.  
  //The %c is tied to &plusFlag.   The ampersand indicates the address of the variable.  The other variables are arrays, and act like the address of the first character in the array.  
  while(fscanf(f, "%8s%*c%c%7s %9s %52s", firCol, &plusFlag, thirCol, fifCol, comm) != EOF)
  {
    printf("%s %c %s %s %s\n", firCol, plusFlag, thirCol, fifCol, comm);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For varying degrees of "proper". I mean, are you REALLY sure that the data is well formatted?  That there's even data in that file? That there's a file at all?  Double-checking all the ways things can go tits up is the difference between life-critical DO-178c code and highschool demos. That and a fuckton of documentation.

Technically, what you're doing should work. You just have extra spaces in your fscanf. So it scanned 8 characters, put them in firCol, then ate a space you thought would be going into `space`, and then put the `+` into space. Try:

```
fscanf(f, "%8c%1c%1c%7c%1c%10c%52c", firCol, space, secCol, thirCol, forCol, fifCol, comm))
```

This DOES read data from a file and put it into your variables...  But I wouldn't call it "proper".  If you want to use strings, you'll find it a lot more compatible with the rest of the programming world if you null terminate them.  This is conforming to... uh... common sense. While there are a million ways to skin a cat, following suit with all the other programmers and libraries and APIs will make your life easier.

Character arrays in C, otherwise known as strings, need a null-terminating character at the end of them `'\0'`.  `'\0'` is the same as the binary value `0` but not the same as the the ascii character `'0'`.

Note the quotes. In C anything in single quotes is a `char`.  'a', 'b', '9','0', along with command characters like '\n' '\0' or '\b'.   Anything in quotes is a string literal. `"This is a string literal"`.  `char` characters pretty much just perform a lookup on the ascii table. Strings on the other hand, act a little funky with a lot of gotchas that screw with people learning the language. Making C strings easier to deal with is one of the primary forces that birthed other languages.

It looks like you wanted to shove this all into a struct. You could do that with:

```
//Outside of main
typedef struct 
{
  char firCol[9];        //first 8 characters including delimiters
  char plusFlag;           //space or '+'
  char thirCol[8];       //word of length 7 but if shorter includes delitimers
  char fifCol[10];       //sames of 7 but length 
  char comm[53];         // length 52 char and delimitrer
} DataFromFile_t;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  DataFromFile_t  dataFromFile;
  . . .
  fscan(f,"%s ...", dataFromFile.firstCol);
```

Lemmesee what else...

- [Generic angry ranting about proper indentation.] And I mean two-spaces and none of this "tab" business the heretics keep blabbering about.
- The importance of showing all the code in your example.
- State what what you have, what you're getting, and what you expected to get in your question. I'm not actually sure what you thought went wrong, I'm just guessing here.
- Don't stress out too much about what "proper". If it gits'er'done, often that's good enough.

Comment: What happens if your `fopen` fails? And why haven't you initialized your arrays? `= {0};`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If only I had mentioned that in the answer. If only.

Answer (score 0):

The key is "This is reading from one line at a time from the file ...", so code that *first*:

```
char buf[100];
while ((fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) != NULL) {
```

*Now*, let us parse the buffer per spec: "... scan in 8 spaces, a word of length 5, 1 space, and another word of length 8 ...".  Using `"%n"` to record the offset of the current scan makes validation easy.

```
  int sp1, sp2;
  int n = 0;
  char word5[5+1];
  char word8[8+1];
  sscanf(" %n%5s %n%8s %n", &sp1, word5, &sp2, word8, &n);
  if (n == 0 || sp1 != 8 || strlen(word5) != 5 || sp2 != (8+5+1) || 
      strlen(word8) != 8) {
    Handle_BadInput();
    continue;
  }
  // Use validated input;
}
```